# Method 'get_Info' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Infrastructure.Internal.SqlServerOptionsExtension

Tags: entity-framework-core

I upgraded my web api from .netcore2.1 to 3.1 and updated all nuget packages to their latest version.
Now my api throws the following error

```
{"StatusCode":500,"ErrorMessage":"Internal server error: Method 'get_Info' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Infrastructure.Internal.SqlServerOptionsExtension' 
from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation
Stack:   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer
at MyApi3.Startup.<ConfigureServices>b__4_0(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) in D:\\a\\1\\s\\MyApi3\\Startup.cs:line 58\  
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<AddDbContext>b__0(IServiceProvider p, DbContextOptionsBuilder b)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.CreateDbContextOptions[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<AddCoreServices>b__0(IServiceProvider p)
at ResolveService(ILEmitResolverBuilderRuntimeContext , ServiceProviderEngineScope ) 
at ResolveService(ILEmitResolverBuilderRuntimeContext , ServiceProviderEngineScope )
at ResolveService(ILEmitResolverBuilderRuntimeContext , ServiceProviderEngineScope )
at ResolveService(ILEmitResolverBuilderRuntimeContext , ServiceProviderEngineScope )
at ResolveService(ILEmitResolverBuilderRuntimeContext , ServiceProviderEngineScope )
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
-- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)","SystemMessage":"Method 'get_Info' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Infrastructure.Internal.SqlServerOptionsExtension' 
from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation."}
```

Answer (score 21):

I added the following packages and the issue was solved

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLServer (3.1.2)
and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (3.1.2)
```

Interesting that I got a runtime error not a build error.

Comment: I wonder if the error being runtime rather than build is due to using SwaggerMiddleware

Comment: I am not using swagger and still got this as a runtime error when upgrading.